# Google Apps Script, create a csv file and keep appending

Tags: google-apps-script

I'd like to create a csv file by appending to the file, rather than create file in one go. Is that possible?

[DriveApp.createFile](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app) uses one go creation. Can there be problems where I read a huge number of records and would rather grab so many records and append to file? Is there a limit to the size of array I create in google apps script ? I am thinking of going over half a million records in csv file. Thanks.

Comment: I believe you will have to get the file as dataString, [`blob.getDataString()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob#getDataAsString()) and append the data by string manipulation, then remove the old file and create a new file to replace it.

Comment: You'd be better off with a true database solution rather than reading from/writing to a flat file. If you need to stay within Google's ecosystem check out cloud datastore, cloud firestore, cloud spanner or  cloud sql. They are all pay-to-play services but if you continue along this path you'd be essentially writing a custom CRUD api to manage csv files which is not something one should attempt without extensive experience developing database architecture from the ground up.

Comment: In addition to @DimuDesigns recommendations, there is Google's FusionTables experiment. If all you plan to do is add / batch add rows, download the file, or replace the existing file with new content, it's a viable solution. If you need to do lots of edits to existing rows, it gets to be painful.

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Script does not have an "append" method using Drive API,

You can create a file and then update it's entire content like below:

```
function appendDataToCSV(content){
  var fileId = '', // update this file with it's ID
      csvFile = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId),
      currentFileContent = "",
      stringContent = "",
      delimiter = ";";
  
  //in case your content is a 2D array like:
  // [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
  if(content instanceof Array){
    for(var i=0;i<content.length;i++){
      stringContent += (content[i].join ? content[i] : content).join(delimiter);
    }
  }
  
  stringContent = stringContent || content || "";
  
  if(stringContent){
    // get file's current text content
    currentFileContent = csvFile.getBlob().getDataAsString();
    
    // update the csv file with its previous content + the new one adding a new row between
    csvFile.setContent(currentFileContent + "\n" + stringContent);
  }
  return "CSV File updated! New size: "+csvFile.getSize();
}
```

But, it has a 10MB max file size limitation;

Best regards!